¿como hago para que sean imagenes redondas?
¿Por qué cuando pongo un border-radius: 50% la foto queda ovalada?

quiero que quede en un circulo. He cambiado de imagen 3 veces y todas quedan ovaladas con este código en css:
.img {
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    
}

cuando le modifico el height al mismo tamaño del width queda redonda pero se ve rara, se ve distorsionada quiero que se vea bien proporcionada pero redonda ¿saben a que se debe que se distorsione así?


Buen día, si alguna respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Lectura recomendada ¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.

Puedes usar las siguientes opciones:
.img{
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    aspect-ratio: 1; /* Se ajusta al mismo valor que el width */
    object-fit: cover;
}

Otra opción es establecer un width y height con el mismo valor de 200px:
.img{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    object-fit: cover;
}


se ve distorsionada cuando le arreglo el height  :( yo vi a alguien haciendo eso con las imágenes y no se le dañaban para nada solo se volvían redondas

Es que si el elemento padre donde esta la imagen dentro tiene un height por ejemplo de 100px y la imagen tiene 512x512 pixeles de tamaño es normal que el width se alargue como se ve en tu imagen y el height se quede como máximo en los 100px haciendo que se vea ovalado, todo dependerá como te digo del contenedor donde esté la imagen (pueden ser varios motivos, ya depende como tengas el resto de tu css)

Si puedes añadir tú código HTML también mucho mejor, para que no se distorsione la imagen puedes usar object-fit: cover

GRACIAS Si me funcionó esa propiedad y me quedó como quería. Pero me quedo con la incógnita de porqué antes se ponía ovalada con el 50%, esa imagen esta dentro de un div y tiene un width de 300 , de resto nada mas tiene medidas

Buen día,
Si la imagen que deseas utilizar no tiene el mismo ancho y alto entonces puedes utilizar un contenedor y darle propiedades a ese contenedor para aplicar el borde circular y centrar la imagen.
Ejemplo con una imagen genérica de 200x100, como se puede ver, se centra y se aplica el borde circular.


.contenedor {
  width: 100px; /* Configurar con el diámetro deseado */
  height: 100px; /* La altura debe ser igual al ancho */
  border-radius: 50%; /* Hacer el borde circular */
  overflow: hidden; /* Esconder el sobrante */
  display: flex; /* Para centrar la imagen */
  justify-content: center; /* Centrar la imagen horizontalmente */
  align-items: center; /* Centrar la imagen verticalmente */
}

.imagen {
  width: auto; /* Mantener el aspect ratio */
  height: 100%; /* Asegurarse de que la imagen cubra el 100% de la altura */
}
<div class="contenedor">
  <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/200x100/" class="imagen" alt="Persona">
</div>



